# Else...if statements not working in my form...? Can I use try-catch instead..?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a login window with username and password. I have a data table which has the user information and I am using an else..if statement when a user tries to login (towards the end of the code). It's suppose to check the username and password and verify that it matches what's in the table. If it doesn't, than a messagebox was suppose to appear. Also, towards the last else...if statement  the user JANITOR doesn't login at all! What can be causing this issue? They all login fine except that last user JANITOR and my messagebox isn't showing up!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class Room : Form
    {
        public Room()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PassText.PasswordChar = '*';
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            FloorSelection ss = new FloorSelection();
            ss.Show();

        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void EXIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\UserData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From dbo.[LOGIN] where username='" + UserText.Text + "' and Password ='" + PassText.Text + "'", con);
            FloorSelection ss = new FloorSelection();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select TYPE From dbo.[LOGIN] where username='" + UserText.Text + "' and Password ='" + PassText.Text + "'", con);
                FloorSelection ss1 = new FloorSelection();
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();


                sda1.Fill(dt1);
                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "FACULTY")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    FACULTY ff = new FACULTY();
                    ff.Show();
                }

                else if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "ADMINISTRATOR")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    ADMINISTRATOR Ad = new ADMINISTRATOR();
                    Ad.Show();
                }

                else if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "JANITOR")
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    JANITOR jt = new JANITOR();
                    jt.Show();

                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Please check your username and password");
                }
            }
        }
        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        private void UserText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserText.BackColor = Color.Empty;
        }

        private void PassText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PassText.BackColor = Color.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

[PICTURE OF MY TABLE DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR9gs.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the logical flow.  My guess is that you have white space in your input.   Try this:

```
string userName = UserText.Text.Trim();
string passwrd = PassText.Text.Trim();
```

This will remove spaces and tabs from the input.  Now replace all the places you use UserText.Text with userName and also replace PassText.Text with passwrd.

You might also want to try creating a variable for that TYPE field like this:

```
string userType = dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim();
```

For example:

```
private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = UserText.Text.Trim();
    string passwrd = PassText.Text.Trim();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\UserData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From dbo.[LOGIN] where username='" + userName + "' and Password ='" + passwrd  + "'", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
```

I hope that helps.

I assume this is a learning project that won't be used in a real world scenario.  If not please rethink what you are doing.  You really shouldn't be rolling your own security system.  You have a classic SQL injection attack vulnerability in your code that would compromise your entire system.

If this is a school project continue with what you are doing, but you might want to ask you professor what a SQL injection attack is.

Good luck!

Comment: Replacing names will screw up the whole project as I have to fix all the windows. Any other way? Maybe using different functions?

Comment: You don't need to 'replace' anything.  Just declare and use the variables inside the xButton1_Click method.  That way you won't affect anything outside the method but just cleaning up the input used inside that method.

Comment: Where do I place the `String` variables in your answer?

Comment: Well that seemed to fix my login issues but what about my messagebox issue? It's suppose to pop up when the wrong credentials are entered!

Comment: Move the else statement of the messagebox outside the inner ifs. Else should be related to the first if not the other ones.

Comment: What do you mean move? Can you give an example? (Sorry, I'm new to C#) lol

Comment: Walking through this code with the Visual Studio debugger should help you see what is happening.  Select a line of code that you want to break on and then hit the F9 key to create a break point.  Then hit F5 to start the debugger.  When the program reaches your break point you can inspect your variables in the 'Watch' window.  Use the F10 key to advance one statement at a time

Comment: @Sergiu is saying that your first if statement where you check == "1" will prevent the code from reaching the MessageBox.Show method call

Comment: Do you think I should get rid of my first if statement with "1"?